# How to use the vibration service in a shared project Xamarin.Forms (Portable) in Visual Studio?

Tags: xamarin, vibration

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App1
{

  public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
  {
      public Page1()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
      }

      void OnButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
      {
          /* code to vibrate */
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please list things you have already tried, or sources you have already read.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this myself but the simplest solution is to use the component developed already called [CrossVibrate](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/VibratePlugin).

In general, you just have to create an abstraction (Interface) and implement it for each OS. This component handles this for you.